# Implement varImp for variable importance and plot

Tags: r, r-caret

[image]I'm trying to plot the variable importance scores for the below model.

The scores output fine but they're not plotting properly- do I need to add another parameter to the code?

Code and Output of Scores are below.

```
library(caret)
#GENERALISED LINEAR MODEL
LR_swim <- lm(racetime_mins ~ event_date+ event_month +year +event_id + 
            gender + distance_new + New_Condition+
            raceNo_Updated +  
            handicap_mins +points+
              Wind_Speed_knots+ 
             Air_Temp_Celsius +Water_Temp_Celsius +Wave_Height_m,
               data = SwimmingTrain) 
           family=gaussian(link = "identity")

varImp2<-varImp(object=LR_swim)
plot(varImp2,main="Variable Importance")
```

Overall
event_date          24.463358
event_month         22.358448
year                24.399390
event_id            26.878342
genderfemale        30.422470
gendermale          13.273062
distance_new       248.727351
New_Condition       22.574999
raceNo_Updated       9.812053
handicap_mins      134.914137
points              40.443116
Wind_Speed_knots    14.492203
Air_Temp_Celsius    16.562194
Water_Temp_Celsius   2.861662
Wave_Height_m        8.592716

```
#ClassOutput
class(varImp2)
[1] "data.frame"
#HeadOutput
> head(varImp2)
          Overall
event_date   24.46336
event_month  22.35845
year         24.39939
event_id     26.87834
genderfemale 30.42247
gendermale   13.27306
```

Mine looks like;

Supposed to look like

[image]

Comment: Can you add the `class(vaImp2)` and `head(varImp2)` in your question? So we can see the format and type of the  `vaImp2`.

Comment: @maydin added above!

Comment: Did you try `plot(varImp2[,1],main="Variable Importance")` ?

Comment: I added what my plot looks like now, what i'm looking for is the variables to be on the y axis and the importance score on the x

Comment: There is only one column in your dataset which is called Overall...So I don't get what is the other one? Do you want to use the rownames as the x value even if they are characters?

Comment: I've added picture of what it's supposed to look like (ignore variable names in picture, taken from example)

Comment: Well.. I am sorry, but as I said, I can only see one variable in your `varImp2` data which is `Overall `column. I can't see the importance score etc. Maybe someone can see what I can't and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the commands I have asked if the rownames of the `varImp2` are the desired x values in your plot or not,  but you did not tell. In any case, assuming the rownames are the y values you want to assign, those codes give you the desired plot, you may arrange the x and y by yourself.

```
library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(data= varImp2, aes(x=rownames(varImp2),y=Overall)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity",width = 0, color = "black") + 
  coord_flip() + geom_point(color='skyblue') + xlab(" Importance Score")+
  ggtitle("Variable Importance") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired outcome, your goal is to plot a numeric column from a dataframe, ordered on the y-axis by the values in the column. I'll use the `mtcars` dataset as an example.

```
library(caret)
LR_mtcars <- glm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, family = gaussian)
varImp2 <- varImp(LR_mtcars)
```

`varImp2` is a dataframe. Now add a column named "labels". We'll make this column a `factor`, and then order it based on values from "Overall".

```
varImp2$labels <- factor(rownames(varImp2))
varImp2$labels <- reorder(varImp2$labels, varImp2$Overall)
```

We can then plot the values. For the first iteration of the plot we leave the titles for the x- and y- axis blank, as well as the labels for the y-axis. We then add those back in subsequently.

```
plot(x = varImp2$Overall, y = varImp2$labels, main = "Variable Importance", 
  yaxt = "n", ylab = "", xlab = "")
axis(2, at = 1:nrow(varImp2), labels = levels(varImp2$labels), las = 2)
title(xlab = "Importance")
```

This gives us

[image]